# how to import huge .mx files faster

Tags: dumpsave

There are some questions/answers regarding efficiency of importing large files faster, but I don't think my point got addressed here.

For instance importing a large file of 4 GB via DumpGet[] takes on average 1614 seconds, which is ridiculously long. And yes, this file type is .mx that I am trying to import.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What does `Import`get you?

Comment: I didn't know that I am allowed to import DumpSave .mx files via Import[]; I will try in a bit and let you know. Good point.

Comment: I know `DumpSave` gets you your definitions too, but `Import` and `Export` both work on `.mx`, so I don’t see why it should not work.

Comment: So importing via DumGet[] takes 2954 seconds and via Import[] 2925, which I think are not due to Import[]'s better efficiencies but due to internal processes. In any event, I don't consider this to be an improvement at all. Any other suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: me either on the efficiencies. Another thing that might be the issue is the use of `DumpSave` itself. As it saves the shape of the internal structures and functional references we have set, i presume it would take up a considerably larger amount of space, and thus time. One possible workaround to this would be to have a pre-decided upon data structure of your tree of data, and then `Export` that, without taking with it the internal references. What I mean by this is that instead of taking `{a,b}={Range[10000],Range[10000]^2}` you take just `{Range[10000],Range[10000]^2}`. To recall

Comment: this, you would just use `{a,b}=Import[%]` where `%` refers to the previously exported data which you had done with `Export[“data.mx”, expr]` where `expr` refers to what I previously wrote about `Range`s. Does this make sense?

Comment: yes, thank you for the idea, but that means I would have to rewrite everything . this is not what i planned on doing or have time to do.

Comment: there's no need to rewrite everything, honest! I presume you are outputting something that has a reference, correct? By this I mean something you `Set` with `=` to call the value of it later? Something like: `varA=somefunction[avar,bvar,...]`? All you would need to do is contain those `varA`s in a list `{varA,varB,...}` and then have that be the target of your `Export`. Quite possibly, depending on how you've written everything, you could even just have the target of your `DumpSave` be the target of your `Export`.

Comment: I am actually dumpsaving the global state of the kernel since that particular expression I cannot dumpsave due to context conflict problems.

Comment: Aha! Well, without any code, it seems this may just be a numbers game. There may be certain structures that cause the slow output, and while solutions do exist that I know of, none of them are ones I could properly iterate to you. Though, I do know there may be more efficient methods of saving the state of the kernel. (You are, then, also saving all of the histories up until that point, too, remember!)